# NSCalendar returns nil and 0 for all values?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] init];
NSDateComponents *tcomponents = [cal components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSLog(@"-%@",cal); //gets null
NSLog(@"-%@",tcomponents); //gets null
```

Whats wrong with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calendar does not exists

the designated initialiser is

```
- (id)initWithCalendarIdentifier:(NSString *)string
```

with

```
NSString * const NSGregorianCalendar;
NSString * const NSBuddhistCalendar;
NSString * const NSChineseCalendar;
NSString * const NSHebrewCalendar;
NSString * const NSIslamicCalendar;
NSString * const NSIslamicCivilCalendar;
NSString * const NSJapaneseCalendar;
NSString * const NSRepublicOfChinaCalendar;
NSString * const NSPersianCalendar;
NSString * const NSIndianCalendar;
NSString * const NSISO8601Calendar;
```

being valid identifiers.

---

or simply

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
```